# ActiveRecordNotFound on wisper publish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, sidekiq, wisper

We have a model ChatRoom which has many messages, the ChatRoom implements `add_message` and receives the parameters for the message along with a boolean `notify` which specifies whether we should send an email or not for the created message.

We publish `:message_created` after the message is created, however in our subscriber we receive an ActiveRecordNotFound error however there is an ID present meaning that the message is persisted in the database.

We have a couple potential fixes however we want to understand the problem and it's cause.

```
class ChatRoom < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :messages, -> { order(:created_at) }

  def add_message(args)
    content = args.fetch(:content)
    creator = args.fetch(:creator)
    notify = args.fetch(:notify, false)

    message = self.messages.create!(content: content, creator: creator)
    publish(:message_created, message_id: message.id, notify: notify)
  end
end
```

```
class MessageCreated::MailChatSubscriber < ApplicationSubscriber
  def message_created(args)
    message = Message.find(args.fetch(:message_id))
    notify = args.fetch(:notify)

    Messages::Organizers::SendChatResponseMail.call(
      message: message,
      notify: notify
    )
  end
end
```

The error is presented below:
`Couldn't find Message with 'id'=575565`

Comment: Is it an option to pass the complete message instead of just the id? You got to use the full message in the `MessageCreated` class anyway. It might be some kind of caching or concurrency problem.

Comment: We though of doing that but it is considered bad practice to pass ActiveRecord Models to subscribers instead of primitives.

Comment: Found the answer in the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631559/sidekiq-not-finding-id-even-after-transaction?noredirect=1#comment130025259_73631559